# Tefillah/tehillim for success in passing an exam

Tags: tehilim-psalms

I'm taking my road test for the third time tomorrow. Is there a specific perek of tehillim I could say to help me pass?

Comment: Good luck! See here: https://www.tehillim-center.co.il/sgula/68

Comment: More important is spending all the time necessary to making sure you are a safe enough driver to not hurt others or yourself in the future. If you need divine intervention to pass the test then you should probably be praying for it for every time you drive.

Comment: I know that. I'm not ignoring basic safety or practice. I'm just asking for hashgacha pratis to succeed.